# Слетели переводы при загрузке картинки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, загрузка-изображения

В окне выбора файла:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в процессе загрузки:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подтянул прежние переводы. Будет на сайта после подкачки transifex и пересборки движка.